# Distribution of vector of $n$ Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, multinomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I have a random variable $X\in\{-1, 1\}^n$ that is just a vector of length $n$ containing either $-1$ or $+1$. I know that $\rho$ is the probability of the event $X = +1$. I would like to describe the distribution of $X$.

> What is the distribution of $X$?

The expression of the distribution for for $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is
$$
\mu(dx) = \prod_{i=1}^n \rho\delta_{+1}(dx_i) + (1-\rho)\delta_{-1}(dx_i)
$$
but what is the name of this distribution?

Comment: It's a recoded Bernoulli distribution with $X=2Y -1$ where $Y$ has a Bernoulli($p$) distribution. I have encountered the name Rademacher($p$) distribution.

Comment: The distribution of $X$ is not determined by the information given, unless perhaps you are implicitly supposing the $X_i$ are *independent.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $X_i$'s are independent, you got the joint distribution right. As for the name, not every distribution has a name. There are infinitely many possible distributions, we didn't name them all.